# Exclude empty or null column with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to exclude empty or null columns when getting collections with Laravel Eloquent ?

I tried this but unsuccessfully:

```
User::where('last_name', 'foo')->get()->filter()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @pr1nc3 answer, there is a method `->reject()` for this specific purpose. It rejects/excludes the items that match the condition. For your case, use it like this:

```
User::where('last_name', 'foo')->get()->reject(function ($value) { return empty($value); });
```

All the values that meet the condition `empty($value)` i.e. the values that are null/empty will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the filter in 2 steps

```
$users = User::where('last_name', 'foo')->get(); //returns your collection
```

Then you can use filter for your collection like:

```
$myFilteredCollection = $users->filter(function ($value) { return !empty($value); });
```

If you still need it in one line then you can do:

Of course you can merge it into one, `get()` actually outputs the collections but looks a bit ugly i think. Keep your actions separate.

```
  $users = User::where('last_name', 'foo')->get()->filter(function ($value) { return !empty($value); });
```

Comment: How do you merge it into one ?

Comment: like you did just format the filter based on my code. Also made some modifications so check again my answer