# I want to query from model of laravel to remove the columns that has only null values in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I used Eloquent query to extract the below table

```
**$ user = User::all()
**
id q1    q2   q3    q4     q5   q6    q7   
0  0.01  0.8  null  0.9   null  0.9   0.1
1  0.8   null null  1     null   1    null
2  null  null null  0.03  null  0.03  null
3  0.04  0.4  null  0.9   null  0.5   null
4  null  0.67 null  0.8   null    9   0.8
5  0.07  0.9  null  0.6   null   10   null
6   1    null null   1    null  0.05  null
```

```
The final table should look like this
id q1    q2      q4      q6    q7   
0  0.01  0.8    0.9     0.9   0.1
1  0.8   null   1        1    null
2  null  null   0.03    0.03  null
3  0.04  0.4    0.9     0.5   null
4  null  0.67   0.8       9   0.8
5  0.07  0.9    0.6      10   null
6   1    null    1      0.05  null
```

I  need to query the model in the laravel by removing the column that has only null values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597995/exclude-empty-or-null-column-with-laravel-eloquent

Comment: my answer has been updated below. kindly check. it is now tested 100% working. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

On your Controller:

```
$q1 = $q2 = $q3 = $q4 = $q5 = $q6 = $q7 = false;

foreach($users as $user){
  if(!$q1){ $q1 = $user->q1 ? true : false; }
  if(!$q2){ $q2 = $user->q2 ? true : false; }
  if(!$q3){ $q3 = $user->q3 ? true : false; }
  if(!$q4){ $q4 = $user->q4 ? true : false; }
  if(!$q5){ $q5 = $user->q5 ? true : false; }
  if(!$q6){ $q6 = $user->q6 ? true : false; }
  if(!$q7){ $q7 = $user->q7 ? true : false; }
}
```

at this point, you'll know what column is true or false. You will only display all columns that has `true` value.

Throw the $users, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7 variables on blade files.

```
<table>

@foreach($users as $user)

<tr>
  @for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++)
    @if($q$i)
      <td>
        {{ $user->q$i }}
      </td>
    @endif
  @endfor
</tr>
@endforeach

</table>
```

**UPDATE:**

This one is now tested working.

I only tweaked some codes for the blade file as follows:

```
<table class="table">

  @foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
      @for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++)
        @php
          $this_value = 'q'.$i;
        @endphp

        @if($$this_value)
          <td>
            {{ $user->$this_value }}
          </td>
        @endif
      @endfor
    </tr>
  @endforeach

</table>
```

Comment: sorry.it is not working

Comment: @laravelphp - please check the `UPDATE` part. it has been tested working. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This help bases on this idea: All null values will become only one null value after using `array_unique([$array_of_null_values])`.

So you can do like me as:

Set the content of Controller `app\Http\Controllers\BasicController.php`.

```
class BasicController extends Controller
{
    function process(Request $request){
        // $q1 = array_unique(User::pluck('q1')->toArray());
        // $q3 = array_unique(User::pluck('q3')->toArray());
        // dd($q1,$q3===array(null));
        $excludes = [];
        $includes = [];
        for ($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){
            ${'q' . $i} = array_unique(User::pluck('q'. $i)->toArray());
            if(${'q' . $i}===array(null)) {
                $excludes [] = 'q' . $i;
            }else {
                $includes [] = 'q' . $i;
            }
        }
        $users = User::select(['id',...$includes])->get();
        return view('process', ['users'=>$users,'includes'=>$includes]);
    }
}
```

Reuse $includes from controller as blade `resources\views\process.blade.php`.

```
<body>
    <p>Users with some includes fields:</p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            @for($i=0;$i<count($includes);$i++)
                <th>{{ $includes[$i] }}</th>
            @endfor
        </tr>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
            @for($i=0;$i<count($includes);$i++)
                @if($user->{ $includes[$i] })
                    <td>{{ $user->{$includes[$i]} }}</td>
                @else
                    <td> null </td>
                @endif
            @endfor
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</body>
```

And you will get desired result.

[image: Final picture]